# A question on differentiable functions on manifolds and the so-called "Hadamard's Lemma"

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, smooth-manifolds

I've been trying to prove Hadamard's lemma for smooth functions:

*"For any smooth function* $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ *and any* $a=(a^{1},\ldots,a^{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ *there exist* $C^{\infty}$ *functions* $H_{\mu}$ *such that for all* $x=(x^{1},\ldots,x^{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ 
$$F(x)=F(a)+\sum_{\mu =1}^{n}\left(x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}\right)H_{\mu}(x)$$ *Furthermore, the functions* $H_{\mu}$ *satisfy* $$H_{\mu}(a)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{\mu}}\bigg\vert_{x=a}."$$

I'm unsure whether I've proceeded correctly. Here is the start of my attempt so far.

Let $\gamma :[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\gamma (0)=a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\gamma (1)=x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, hence a *fixed* value of $t\in [0,1]$ identifies a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by $\gamma (t)$. The curve $\gamma$ is such that it passes through the fixed point $a\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and some arbitrary point $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The coordinate representation of the curve is given by $$\gamma (t)=\left(x^{1}(t),\ldots,x^{n}(t)\right)=\gamma (0)+t\left(\gamma (1)-\gamma (0)\right)=a+t\left(x-a\right)$$ where $x^{\mu}:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are the coordinate functions that specify the coordinates of the curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ for each value of $t\in [0,1]$. We thus define the coordinate functions $x^{\mu}$ such that $$x^{\mu}(t)=a^{\mu}+t\left(x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}\right)$$ where $a^{\mu}, x^{\mu}\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now consider the function $h:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, defined such that  $$h(t)=(F\circ\gamma)(t)=F(\gamma(t))=F(a+t(x-a))$$ where $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $C^{\infty}$. It follows that $$\frac{dh}{dt}=h'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left[(F\circ\gamma)(t)\right]=\frac{d}{dt}\left[F\left((x^{1}(t),\ldots,x^{n}(t))\right)\right]\\ \qquad=\sum_{\mu =1}^{n}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}=\sum_{\mu =1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\left[F(a+t(x-a))\right]\left(x^{\mu}-a^{\mu}\right).$$

If this first part is correct I'm fairly sure that I can complete the rest, but I'm unsure as to whether I've set it up correctly?! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems convoluted. Did you look at the proof given on Wikipedia?

Comment: Yes, but I just wanted to justify it a bit more and check my understanding, e.g why one can write $\frac{\partial F (a+t(x-a))}{\partial x^{\mu}}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mathematician, but I think you are probably on the right track.

$\gamma(t)$ links the point $a$ and $x$. You've found nice expressions for $H_{\mu}(x)$, for integrating your last eq. for $h^{'}(t)$ from $0$ to $1$, you will get $F(x) - F(a) = \int_0^1 d t \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[ F(a+t(x-a)) \right] (x^{\mu} - a^{\mu})$; thus, $H^{\mu}(x) = \int_0^1 d t \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[ F(a+t(x-a)) \right]$.

The only other thing that remains to be proved is that $H^{\mu}(x)$ is smooth. I'm no mathematician, but I think all you need to show is that all partial derivatives of $H^{\mu}(x)$ with respect to $x$ exist and are continuous. This follows from the fact that $F(x)$ is smooth, and I think it's legitimate (?; in doubt) to exchange the operation of integration and partial differentiation. For example, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{nu}} \int_0^1 d t \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \left[ F(a+t(x-a)) \right] = \int_0^1 d t \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^{\mu} x^{\nu}} \left[ F(a+t(x-a)) \right]$

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The main bit that I'm unsure about is whether this part is valid: $\gamma (t)=\left(x^{1}(t),\ldots,x^{n}(t)\right)=\gamma (0)+t\left(\gamma (1)-\gamma (0)\right)=a+t\left(x-a\right)$? Can one assume this and still claim a general result?

Comment: $x$ is from $R^n$. $\gamma(t)$ is just a straight line connecting $a$ and $x$. I think this operation is valid (in $R^n$).

Comment: That's what I thought, but then I showed it to someone else, and they said it wasn't valid as the expression for $\gamma$ (as I gave it) could only ever (at best) be an approximation of a curve?! I though it was satisfactory as it satisfies the required boundary conditions?!

Comment: What do you mean by "could only ever (at best) be an approximation of a curve"? A straight line is a curve.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I don't know whether he just misunderstood what I was trying to convey, or whether he was trying to say that one couldn't use such a straight line to prove that the case is true in general?!

Comment: Then you have to ask him where does the proof goes wrong. Probably exchanging the operation of integration and partial differentiation is a bit dangerous. But I think for nice functions it's possible.

Comment: You're right, I'll have to ask him. Personally, I thought it was fine, but then again, I'm not a pure mathematician.